# How do I merge column values from one dataframe to another if they are not present in another using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have two different excel files which I read using `pd.readExcel`. The first excel file is kind of a master file which has a lot of columns. showing only those columns which are relevant:
df1

```
Company Name                                              Excel Company ID
0                                    cleverbridge AG      IQ109133656
1  BT España, Compañía de Servicios Globales de T...        IQ3806173
2                                   Technoserv Group       IQ40333012
3                                    Blue Media S.A.       IQ50008102
4            zeb.rolfes.schierenbeck.associates gmbh       IQ30413992
```

and the second excel is basically an output excel file which looks like this:
df2

```
company_id          found_keywords  no_of_url                                       company_name
0  IQ137156215      insurance         15                         Zühlke Technology Group AG
1    IQ3806173      insurance         15  BT España, Compañía de Servicios Globales de T...
2   IQ40333012      insurance          4                                   Technoserv Group
3   IQ51614192      insurance         15                             Octo Telematics S.p.A.
```

I want this output excel file/ df2 to include those company_id and company name from df1 where company id and company name from df1 is not a part of df2. Something like this:
df2

```
company_id found_keywords  no_of_url                                       company_name
0  IQ137156215      insurance         15                         Zühlke Technology Group AG
1    IQ3806173      insurance         15  BT España, Compañía de Servicios Globales de T...
2   IQ40333012      insurance          4                                   Technoserv Group
3   IQ51614192      insurance         15                             Octo Telematics S.p.A.
4   IQ30413992      NaN               NaN              zeb.rolfes.schierenbeck.associates gmbh
```

I tried several ways of achieveing this by using `pd.merge` as well as `np.where`
I even tried reindexing based on columns but nothing worked out. What exactly do I need to do so that it works as expected. Please help me out.Thanks!

**EDIT**:

using pd.merge

```
df2.merge(df, right_on='company_id', left_on='Excel Company ID', how='outer')
```

which gave an output with [220 rows X 31 columns]

Comment: Can you check your output, please?

Comment: using pd.merge the shape of the output is 220rows * 31 columns, which is incorrect. I'll update the question the code I used.

Comment: Now for your sample (df1 and df2), what is the expected output?

Comment: @Corralien the expected output is the same like mentioned in the question above

Comment: Why "cleverbridge AG" and "Blue Media S.A." do not appear in the output? What is the difference with "BT España, Compañía de Servicios Globales de T..."?

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output is unclear. If you use `pd.merge` with `how='outer'` and `indicator=True`, you will have:

```
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'Company Name': 'company_name', 'Excel Company ID': 'company_id'})
out = df2.merge(df1, on=['company_id', 'company_name'], how='outer', indicator=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    company_id found_keywords  no_of_url                                       company_name      _merge
0  IQ137156215      insurance       15.0                         Zühlke Technology Group AG   left_only
1    IQ3806173      insurance       15.0  BT España, Compañía de Servicios Globales de T...        both
2   IQ40333012      insurance        4.0                                   Technoserv Group        both
3   IQ51614192      insurance       15.0                             Octo Telematics S.p.A.   left_only
4  IQ109133656            NaN        NaN                                    cleverbridge AG  right_only
5   IQ50008102            NaN        NaN                                    Blue Media S.A.  right_only
6   IQ30413992            NaN        NaN            zeb.rolfes.schierenbeck.associates gmbh  right_only
```

Check the last column `_merge`. If you have `right_only`, it means the `company_id` and `company_name` are not found in `df2`.

Comment: let me test this solution

Comment: yes..I am getting right_only in the last column _merge